# Souncloud error rate_limit while getting authentication token

Tags: php, authentication, soundcloud

My application just stopped getting authentication tokens from soundcloud. I am using php api and sending request as:

```
$client = new Services_Soundcloud(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);
$code = $_GET['code'];
$access_token = $client->accessToken($code);
```

It is returning me the following response since morning:

```
{"errors":[{"meta":{"rate_limit":{"bucket":"by-ip","max_nr_of_requests":100,"time_window":"PT1H","group":"oauth2_token"},"remaining_requests":0,"reset_time":"2015/08/13 12:03:38 +0000"}}]}
```

Till last night it worked fine with the same code.

Comment: I am facing the same issue since morning and not find any solution till

Comment: looks like you reached the max number of request for the day (15,000) https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits

Comment: @Lex : Yes a similar thing is mentioned there, but they have mentioned the limit on play requests. Limitations about authentication requests have not been mentioned anywhere in the soundcloud documentation. Does it generalises for all kind of requests?

Comment: @Vipul it looks like they limiting you to 100. In the error message it reads max_nr_of_requests: 100. In the previous link you see the error message for when you reach the limit of 15,000 max_nr_of_requests: 15000. It may not be documented but thats what it looks like.

Comment: Same issue here. Not using playbacks.

Comment: Everyone should email soundcloud with this stackoverflow link to bring it to their attention: support@soundcloud.com & api@soundcloud.com

Answer (score 1):

SoundCloud, in their infinite wisdom, chose to roll out a rate limit on the /oauth2/token endpoint. They only allow 100 requests/hour from the same IP address. This causes major problems for applications that use the server-side authentication flow, since all requests to the /oauth2/token endpoint for that app originate from the server, causing it to hit the rate limit as soon as the app has more than 100 people try to authenticate within an hour.

I was able to work around this issue by switching to a client-side authentication flow using the [SoundCloud Javascript SDK](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks). This makes it so that your users' browsers make the /oauth2/token requests, and not your servers, which lets you avoid the rate limit.

This is all what I've learned by dealing with the problem myself- SoundCloud hasn't actually publicly released any documentation on this new rate limit. It seems they are becoming less and less developer friendly, so I would be wary of relying on the stability of their API in the future.